# Gap between bumper and trunk

Tags: bumper, trunk

I have a Vitara brezza and I accidentally hit my rear bumper with a heavy bag while I was loading it in the car. There were no scratches or dents when I checked the bumper, however the gap between bumper and trunk seems to have increased. I don't have a photo clicked, however I can share a similar image down here. The bumper seems to be fitting fine from the sides though at the center it's a bit wide. Any ideas how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: More than likely when you hit the bumper, you've either stretched or torn the mounting holes in the bumper, which is allowing it to sag a bit causing the gap. You'll probably need to pull the bumper off and see where damage may have occurred, then what would be needed to fix what you've found. Worst case scenario would involve replacement.

Comment: I checked the gap today in my vehicle and it doesn't seem to be this wide. It's only detached at the center. However, when I tried to push it back it seems to get stuck and then again it reverts back. I also noticed it bends a bit at the hinges when I try to push it. Maybe it's dislocated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to speculate that there are some tabs along this edge that are designed to pop into some slots adjacent to them and hold this into place.  When you bumped it they popped out, perhaps they were already loose due to being removed before.  Perhaps they are mostly broken off.  That's not uncommon.

I'd try to pop them back in.  Look closely and see if you can find where the tabs are and line them up with the slots and then try to push them back in.  It may take a smack with your hand or fist to get them all the way in.

If the tabs are damaged or broken you may have to look at an alternate means of fastening.  Perhaps some zip ties or even some adhesive could be useful.

Comment: Yes there was a sensor replacement done a few weeks back. I will check if there's something loose in between.

Comment: I tried to push the bumper back in but it holds in there for a moment and pops out again as if forced to pull out

Comment: As I mentioned, it's quite possible that the tabs that hold it in place are damaged.  You may need to replace it or find an alternate method of securing it.